# How to find control bounded in item template on master page from content page?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, master-pages

I am having a nested repeater on the master page. And a hiddenfield  in its item template.
i want the value of hiddenfield on content page.Like this

```
<ul class="categories">
                        <li>
                            <div id='cssmenu'>
                                <h4>Categories</h4>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="repcategory" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repcategory_ItemDataBound">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ul>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" Value='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>' runat="server" />
                                        <li class="active has-sub">
                                            <a href='#'><span>
                                                <%#Eval("CategoryName") %></span></a>
                                            <asp:Repeater ID="repsubcategory" OnItemDataBound="repsubcategory_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ul>
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf2" Value='<%# Eval("SubCategoryID") %>' runat="server" />
                                                    <li class="has-sub">
                                                        <a href='#'><span>
                                                            <%#Eval("SubCategoryName") %></span></a>
                                                        <asp:Repeater ID="repsubcategory2" runat="server">
                                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                                <ul>
                                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf3" Value='<%# Eval("SubCategory2ID") %>' runat="server" />
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <a href="ClientProductSubCategory2.aspx"><span>
                                                                        <%#Eval("SubCategory2Name") %></span></a>
                                                                </li>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                        </li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
```

I want the value of subcategory2id on the content page and codded like this.

```
 HiddenField hiddensubcategory2id = (HiddenField)Master.FindControl("hf3");
        DataSet ds = new ClientProductView().GetAllProductSubCategory2(hiddensubcategory2id.Value);
        repContent.DataSource = ds;
        repContent.DataBind();
```

But this is returning a null value. Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the control within the repeater object itself, like this:

```
var hiddensubcategory2id = repsubcategory2.FindControl("hf3") as HiddenField;
```

Note: You should always check to see if the result of a `FindControl()` is null or not, like this:

```
if(hiddensubcategory2id != null)
{
    // Do something with the control you found
}
```

Comment: means i should first find hidden field on master page and store its value in a variable on master page and then call that variable value on content page